# Pulling data from Melissa data base

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull data from the Melissa database, but I keep getting NaN values returned and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse,parseString
import xml.dom.minidom
import requests
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

key = ''

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def getElementValue(p_dom,p_element):
    if len(p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)) > 0:
       l_value=p_dom.getElementsByTagName(p_element)[0]
       return(l_value.firstChild.data)
    else:
       l_value='NaN'
       return(l_value)

def getData(key, full_name, address):
        url = 'https://personator.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/ContactVerify/doContactVerify?id=' + key +'&full=' 
        + full_name +'&a1=' + address
        xml = requests.get(url)
        dom = parseString(xml.text)

        response = dom.getElementsByTagName('response')

        Gender = getElementValue(dom, 'Gender')
        DateOfBirth = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfBirth')
        DateOfDeath = getElementValue(dom, 'DateOfDeath')
        EthnicCode = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicCode')
        EthnicGroup = getElementValue(dom, 'EthnicGroup')
        Education = getElementValue(dom, 'Education')
        PoliticalParty = getElementValue(dom, 'PoliticalParty')
        MaritalStatus = getElementValue(dom, 'MaritalStatus')
        HouseholdSize = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdSize')
        ChildrenAgeRange = getElementValue(dom, 'ChildrenAgeRange')
        PresenceOfChildren = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfChildren')
        PresenceOfSenior = getElementValue(dom, 'PresenceOfSenior')
        LengthOfResidence = getElementValue(dom, 'LengthOfResidence')
        OwnRent = getElementValue(dom, 'OwnRent')
        CreditCardUser = getElementValue(dom, 'CreditCardUser')
        Occupation = getElementValue(dom, 'Occupation')
        HouseholdIncome = getElementValue(dom, 'HouseholdIncome')

        return Gender

df['Gender'] = df.apply(lambda row: getData(key, row['Full Name'], row['Address']), axis = 1)
```

The NaN is being returned from the getElementValue(p_dom,p_element) function.